# Using R find words not matching a string

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

If I have a string

```
x<- c("you are a good boy")
```

and another string

```
y<- c("good","bad","better","worse")
```

Now I want to compare and find which are the words there in x and not in y.
I want them as a separate file. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean words in y that are not in x? What do you mean by "separate files"? This could be of help: `sapply(y, function(matchWord){length(grep(matchWord, x))})`

Comment: Something like `gsub(paste(y,collapse="|"),"",x)`? Please provide desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
 setdiff(strsplit(x, split=" ")[[1]], y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, so what about :

```
sapply(y, function(w) grepl(w,x))
```